# Export custom android eclipse project to maven build type

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

The goal was to export existing android `eclipse` project to maven type. To do this, it was required to download `.m2 plugin`. Right click on project and `Configure-->Convert To Maven Project`, what opened the window "`Create new POM`" with:

[image]

The question is what should be selected in packaging type while there is only `jar/pom/war` . I believe there should be "`apklib`" but when we type it there after `pom.xml` generation:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>X.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Name</groupId>
  <artifactId>Artifact</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>apklib</packaging>
</project>
```

Eclipse response with :

```
Project build error: Unknown packaging: apklib
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

maven has no built-in packaging "apklib", which is probably why youre getting the error.

you havent specified which maven plugin youre using to build android artifacts, but assumming its [this one](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) your pom needs to look like this (taken from their [samples](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Samples))

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.simpligility.android</groupId>
<artifactId>helloflashlight</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<name>HelloFlashlight</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.2</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <!-- platform as api level (api level 16 = platform 4.1)-->
                    <platform>16</platform>
                </sdk>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: If your pom.xml is ok, should I hardcode it or there is any way to generate it based on the custom no-maven-project in any smart way?

Comment: @Kuba - you should obviously correct the project name/version to fit yours, add whatever libraries you depend on etc, but the pom i pasted should work as a starting point. as for IDEs, there's no IDE that i know of thats really capable of handling all maven projects. at some point you stray far enough from a simple project and lose proper IDE support. eclipse, IMHO, is one of the worst IDEs in terms of maven support. what im saying is that you should learn to use maven directly. from the command line. the knowledge will serve you well.